# How to point a URL:PORT to specific directory in apache

Tags: php, apache, centos, virtualhost

I have **Centos** server and using PHP and Yii Framework. I have following configuration in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
Alias /test "/var/www/test/"
<Directory "/var/www/test/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I point `ip.ip.ip.ip/test` in browser, it shows my project in `/var/www/test/` which is fine. Now I want to access my project in `/var/www/test/` using following URL:

```
ip.ip.ip.ip:8080
```

Is it possible.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Apache Virtual Hosts mechanism for that:

```
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    <Directory />
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I added above code at the end of the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. Now I am getting errors while restarting apache server. Any idea?

Comment: I've just updated my answer, try it again please.

Comment: getting following error: `Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for bPay-Demo.csquareonline.com
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8080
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
`

Comment: The problem that your 8080 port is already taken by some software, try to change it to 54321 for example.

Comment: Some progress. I used `54321` port and I didn't get any error while restarting Apache Server. But when I used `ip.ip.ip.ip:54321` in browser, it is taking too much time and getting following error in the end. `The connection has timed out`.. thanks for your help.

Comment: But your /test alias is still working? Maybe server refuses connections on this port? Do you use developer's machine as server? Or is it production one?

Comment: it is for development testing.

Comment: Please add `ErrorLog /var/log/apache/www.foo.com-error.log` inside of your VirtualHost definition and try again. After that show me recent messages of /var/log/apache/error.log and content of specified VirtualHost error log file.